# Jar try to create service in windows on java wrapper

Tags: java, jsp, service, wrapper

Hellow.

Today in first time I Try to create service in OS Windows used jar.
I try to used **java wrapper community edition 3.5.29**

Create test_service in windows is OK.
For next step I try to start new test_service.
Service try to Startup and down.
In Logs JAVA WRAPPER has this information.

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 | --> Wrapper Started as Service
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.5.29
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:21 |
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:53:22 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/07/19 11:53:22 | [11:53:22 19.07.2016]: Starting Oracle.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/07/19 11:53:22 | [11:53:22 19.07.2016]: Try Update.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/07/19 11:53:22 | [11:53:22 19.07.2016]: Update OK.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 |
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Advice:
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | The Wrapper consists of a native component as well as a set of classes
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | which run within the JVM that it launches.  The Java component of the
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Wrapper must be initialized promptly after the JVM is launched or the
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Wrapper will timeout, as just happened.  Most likely the main class
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | specified in the Wrapper configuration file is not correctly initializing
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | the Wrapper classes:
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 |     COM.MainRunner
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | While it is possible to do so manually, the Wrapper ships with helper
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | classes to make this initialization processes automatic.
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | Please review the integration section of the Wrapper's documentation
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | for the various methods which can be employed to launch an application
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | within the Wrapper:
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate.html
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ADVICE | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 |
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | JVM did not exit on request, termination requested.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:21 | JVM exited after being requested to terminate.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/07/19 11:54:26 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2016/07/19 11:54:26 | [11:54:26 19.07.2016]: Starting Oracle.
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2016/07/19 11:54:26 | [11:54:26 19.07.2016]: Try Update.
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2016/07/19 11:54:27 | [11:54:26 19.07.2016]: Update OK.
```

If I right understand in my Class COM.MainRunner absent some implements on Wrapper.

Please help to simple working example with java wrapper.

Comment: need example java class with  implements WrapperListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this configuration solve problem

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/example.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/wrapper.jar

wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib
wrapper.java.library.path.2=../lib/lib

wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

wrapper.java.additional.1="Oracle"

wrapper.app.parameter.1=
```